# double to int in c

Tags: c, casting

I have this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    double d = 10;
    int x = 5;

    x = (int) d + x;
    d = (double)x + d;

    printf("%lf\n" , d);
    printf("%d\n" , x);
}
```

the out put is :

```
-0.0000
15
```

Why is this working for `int` but not for `double`? 
How to make this work?

Comment: Are you sure? When I run this I get 25.000000 and 15

Comment: You've given us the output of the program. But why is that output wrong? What do you expect it to be? Why do you expect it to be that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C89 use `%f` format specifer to print `double` value. With newer standards you might use `%lf`, in which case `l` has no effect (it was introduced for symmetry with `scanf()`), but it's just asking for trouble, as it's undefined in previous standard.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double d = 10;
    int x = 5;

    x = (int) d + x;
    d = (double)x + d;

    printf("%f\n", d);
    printf("%d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that in C89 you probably should add `return 0;`. With C99/C11 `return 0;` is implicitly added when omitted (with exception to call of `exit()` function directly in `main()`, which serves for that as well).

Comment: Shouldn't `%lf` and `%f` be the same (because `float`/`%f` is promoted to `double`/`%lf` in variadic argument functions? Or is that a non-standard extension?

Comment: `%lf` in `printf` is the same as `%f`, at least since C99.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

http://ideone.com/YBfHau

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    double d = 10;
    int x = 5;

    x = (int) d + x;
    d = (double)x + d;

    printf("%lf\n" , d);
    printf("%d" , x);
return 0;

}
```

EDIT: Remember to add `return 0`

Comment: That would depend on the compiler I guess. Your code is fine

Comment: @Simon `return` is not needed in `main()` in C99. The code was fine without it.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq you need the return 0; when you're compiling on ideone, to avoid a runtime error. Simon's statement is correct. However the answer prints out fine

Comment: @PrasanthLouis In ideone.com, pick “C99” as the language. This has several advantages over C90.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq oh, thank you very much. I stand corrected.